# Format specifier for templated type

Tags: c++, templates, format-specifiers

I've got a C++ class that's templated on the integer type, e.g.,

```cpp
template<typename int_type>
```

Say that somewhere in that class, I'd like to use `sscanf` for reading some values from a file, e.g.,

```cpp
int_type num_rows;
fgets( buffer, BUFSIZE, in_file );
sscanf( buffer, "%d", &num_rows);
```

The format specifier only works correctly if the `int_type` is the intrinsic `int`.

Is there a better way of treating the format specifier for general `int_type`?

Comment: That isn't really templated... sscanf with %d only works with an integer, so the templated type doesn't really matter here. You will need to change the scanf argument as well

Comment: You could have a private static member function that returns `char const *` and specialize it for each distinct `int_type` you intend to support, and use the return value as the format argument to `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `sscanf()` and a format specifier use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) with [`operator>>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

```
if (fgets( buffer, BUFSIZE, in_file ))
{
    std::istringstream in(buffer);
    if (!(in >> num_rows))
    {
        // Handle failure.
    }
}
```

Replacing the (not shown) `FILE*` and with a [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) would enable removal of the `std::istringstream` and just read directly from the `std::ifstream` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can just declare `fmt` in your class and provide explicit values per type in the implementation:

```
// foo.hpp
template< typename T >
class foo
{
private:
    static const char* fmt;

public:
    void print() const
    {
        T num_rows;
        fgets( buffer, BUFSIZE, in_file );
        sscanf( buffer, fmt, &num_rows);
    }
};
```

and

```
// foo.cpp
template<> const char* foo< int >::fmt = "%d";
template<> const char* foo< long >::fmt = "%ld";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create template helper class:

```
template<class int_type>
struct fmt_helper_f{};

template<>
struct fmt_helper_f<int>
{
  static const char * fmt() {return "%d";}
};

template<>
struct fmt_helper_f<float>
{
  static const char * fmt() {return "%f";}
};
```

Actually you may want to use streams for input and output