# Caffe Installation error when making multi_stage_meanfield.cpp

Tags: c++, deep-learning, caffe

Installing caffe on Ubuntu 16.04, I run into the following error when running the command "make":

```
src/caffe/layers/multi_stage_meanfield.cpp:72:13: warning: format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double*’, but argument 3 has type ‘float*’ [-Wformat=]
       fscanf(pFile, "%lf", &this->blobs_[0]->mutable_cpu_data()[i * channels_ + i]);
```

If I change "%lf" into "%f", then I get into another error, namely

```
src/caffe/layers/multi_stage_meanfield.cpp:72:13: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float*’, but argument 3 has type ‘double*’ [-Wformat=]
       fscanf(pFile, "%f", &this->blobs_[0]->mutable_cpu_data()[i * channels_ + i]);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: this is probably happening because you have both float and double type template object defined.

Comment: see the solutions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929326/format-specifier-for-templated-type